# Creating my own event for right button click

Tags: java, swing, mouse, mouseevent, right-click

I have some component on the frame and I need it to respond just on right button click. I have to use my own event. Should I extend `MouseEvent`? How can I separate right button click from others in my event?

Comment: I've tried to create my own class (it requires by task). But I am completely misled. Firstly I've tried to create class that extends EventObject, but I don't know how to make him be exactly right-click event. Than I thought about extending MouseEvent, but I still can't think up how to do it in a proper way. I remind you that I have to create my own event class, not just use java.awt.event.MouseEvent.

Answer (score 6):

No, you wouldn't *extend* MouseEvent, rather you would *use* MouseEvent.

If this is a Swing GUI you could add a MouseListener to the component and then in the MouseListener's mousePressed method, get the MouseEvent object that is passed in to the method, get its modifiersEx and then check if right click has been pressed:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mEvt) {
   if ((mEvt.getModifiersEx() & MouseEvent.BUTTON3_DOWN_MASK) != 0) {
      // right button has been pressed
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. I know such way of solving my problem and I agree that it doesn't necessary to create custom event, but the task is not use Java's MouseEvent, the task is create custom event.

Answer (score 5):

The `MouseEvent` class has a method that allows you to check which mouse button was used. It's called [getButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getButton()) and it returns an `int` value that you can compare to one of [predefined values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#BUTTON1)

On top of that, there's a convenient class called `SwingUtilities`, which provides a nice layer of abstraction over the use of these fields. Here's a method you'll find particularly interesting: [`isRightMouseButton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#isRightMouseButton(java.awt.event.MouseEvent))

In other words, you don't need to create your own `MouseEvent`, a `MouseListener` implementation will suffice. Here's an example of inline implementation, irrelevant details excluded.

```
new MouseListener(){

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if(SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)){
                //do what you want on right click
            }
        }
        // other methods required by the interface

    };
```